# How to select only the characters after a repeated symbol in a long string

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

If i am using C# and i have a string coming in from a database like this:

```
\RBsDC\1031\2011\12\40\1031-215338-5DRH44PUEM2J51GRL7KNCIPV3N-META-ENG-22876500BBDE449FA54E7CF517B2863E.XML
```

And i only want this part of the string:

```
1031-215338-5DRH44PUEM2J51GRL7KNCIPV3N-META-ENG-22876500BBDE449FA54E7CF517B2863E.XML
```

How can i get this string if there is more than one "\" symbol?

Comment: you have to do a IndexOf or you could use the split function or you could parse out all the unnecessary stuff that you don't need.. do you have any code written yourself..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LastIndexOf()` method of the `String` class:

```
 string s = @"\RBsDC\1031\2011\12\40\1031-215338-5DRH44PUEM2J51GRL7KNCIPV3N-META-ENG-22876500BBDE449FA.xml";

 Console.Out.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.Split` to split string by parts and then get the last part.

Using LINQ [Enumerable.Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) :

```
text.Split('\\').Last();
```

or

```
// todo: add null-empty checks, etcs
var parts = text.Split('\\');
strign lastPart = parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

Comment: unfortunately, i am not allowed to use linq.

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr: It's not even really using LINQ.  Just use `Split()` and take the last item... the end.  The LINQ `Last()` is just a convenience method to do just that.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, that really hurt my feelings, there is no call for rudeness.

Comment: Not being rude.. just wondering how you can quickly say you can't use something when Split() is a method that's provided by the .net framework..??

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, i didn't know about it, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of String.LastIndexOf("\") and String.Substring(lastIndex+1). You could also use (only in the sample you provided) Path.GetFileName(theString).

Answer (score 2):

string[] x= line.Split('\');

string goal =x[x.Length-1];

but linq will be easier

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex or split the string by "\" symbol and take the last element of array

```
using System.Linq;

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        string s =
            @"\RBsDC\1031\2011\12\40\1031-215338-5DRH44PUEM2J51GRL7KNCIPV3N-META-ENG-22876500BBDE449FA54E7CF517B2863E.XML";

        var array = s.Split('\\');

        string value = array.Last();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newstring = string.Substring(string.LastIndexOf(@"\")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like original string is like filePath.
This could be one easy solution.

```
string file = @"\RBsDC\1031\2011\12\40\1031-215338-5DRH44PUEM2J51GRL7KNCIPV3N-META-ENG-22876500BBDE449FA.xml";
            string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
```